# How to lock hostname changes in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, hostname, lock

I take care of a computer lab and I need to lock changes in the hostname because of the students.
Ps: They do not have root access

Answer (score 1):

If your "lab" systems are otherwise secure, you don't need to do anything. `/etc/hostname` is protected against casual access:

```
$ ll /etc/hostname
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4 Jan 29 18:08 /etc/hostname
```

Comment: In Settings >> Details >> About  it's possible to change the hostname without root access.